# Laravel 5: Remove development dependancies from app config file

Tags: git, laravel, deployment, composer-php

I'm deploying my Laravel's projects with `git clone` and updating with `git pull`

It works fine, but each time I deploy, I had to remove the development dependancies from `config/app.php` `providers` array and `aliases` array which is annoying and each time I do `composer install --no-dev` , it shows me errors because he didn't found the dev packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally load service providers and facades based on the environment in laravel 5.

#### Service Providers

Service Providers need to be registered in `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` rather than `config/app.php`.

```php
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
        'App\Services\Registrar'
    );

    if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
        $this->app->register('App\Providers\ProductionProvidersGoHere');
    } else {
        $this->app->register('App\Providers\DevelopmentProvidersGoHere');
    }
}
```

For a tutorial have a look here: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/conditionally-loading-service-providers-in-laravel-5

#### Facades

Facades can be conditionally loaded with the `AliasLoader`.

```php
/**
 * List of only Local Enviroment Facade Aliases
 * @var array
 */
protected $facadeAliases = [
    'Debugbar' => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',
];

/**
 * Load additional Aliases
 * Base file Alias load is /config/app.php => aliases
 */
public function registerFacadeAliases()
{
    $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
    foreach ($this->facadeAliases as $alias => $facade)
    {
        $loader->alias($alias, $facade);
    }
}
```

Here is a nice tutorial for this too: http://blog.piotrows.pl/en/laravel-5-load-serviceprovider-depend-on-env-file/

// Edit
added facades:
*Thanks to @Sn0opr for pointing me into this.*

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, but how about Facades, (aliases array)

Comment: for example, I'm using Laravel Debugbar, which has Debugbar facade, how to do that like service providers

Comment: Here I found a solution, I had to use ```AliasLoader``` predefined Laravel Facade that loads facades for the app: 

```AliasLoader::getInstance([
                'Debugbar'  => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',
            ]);```
Please add it to your answer so people can see it